# get a data from child to parent on demand with @input/@output angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

how can i get a object from child to parent without using @viewChild or service?

```
export class MultiSelectComponent implements OnInit {

selectedItems: FormSelectComponentOption[] = [];

@Input()
items: FormSelectComponentOption[];

@Output()
selected = new EventEmitter<FormSelectComponentOption[]>();
}
```

Now, how can i make a "request" to get a whole FormSelectComponentOption?

Comment: You don't make a 'request', if the object is there, it will be available, under this.items

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Should the parent be aware of  changes on `items` (because he is) or do you want to pass a totally different object to parent upon some event like click?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't make a *request* but push the selections to the parent component every time they change.
When the user changes the selections in your MultiSelectComponent you'd call `this.selected.emit(this.selectedItems)` and subscribe to these changes in the template of the parent like `<multi-select (select)="selectionChanged($event)" [items]="items">` and then in your parent you might have the `selectionChanged()` method which saves the new selection.
When you now want to *request* the data, just use the selection saved in your parent.

Comment: i know that and i dont want this type of approach, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `FormSelectComponentOption[]` data to your parent upon some event (for example `click`), you can use emitters.

You can do it like this:

```
//your parent component html
<multi-select (selected)="itemsSelected($event)"></multi-select>

//your parent component class
public class ParentComponent {
  itemsFromChild: FormSelectComponentOption[];

  itemsSelected(FormSelectComponentOption[] items){
    this.itemsFromChild = items;
  }
}

//your child component html
<div (click)="selected.emit(selectedItems);"></div>
```

Comment: ok, but thats still dont resolve my problem. How can i avoid a (click) binding in child?

Comment: i guess the question here is, when do you want to pass data to the parent? On some event? When data gets modified?